# Vue-Firebase: Catching a changed value from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

As my learning of Firebase with vue progresses im finding it unusually difficult to keep an html updating its value from firebase.

If i want to get a single value once i use

```
this.$firebaseRefs.Team_Counter.child('numOfTeam').once("value", function(snapshot){
              Team_number = snapshot.val();
            });
```

Which is fine when the value doesnt update and need to be changed.

But im trying to get a value which updates all the time and is in the html

```
<p>{{Team_Num}}</p>
```

It gets updated once and if i reload the project it will update again but at run time it wont change the value.

I tried using a function that listens to a child change

```
this.$firebaseRefs.Team_Counter.child('numOfTeam').on("child_changed", function(snapshot){
              Team_number = snapshot.val();
            } );
```

Yet im getting the same result as the above code.

Is using

```
on.("child_changed" ...)
```

the correct way to approach this? Or am i missing something else ? Do i need to add something else to that value before i can read that changed data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should listen for [value event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events)

> value: Read and listen for changes to the entire contents of a path.

```
this.$firebaseRefs.Team_Counter.child('numOfTeam').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    // Do whatever
});
```

`once('value')` only runs 1 time, but `on('value')` will be trigger when value changed

Comment: Ah i see it was just the difference between using once and on. Feel kind of foolish now. Thanks!